# VSCode not hitting breakpoints using Go lang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm using Windows and the latest Visual Studio Code (v1.66.0), with the latest "Go" extension (v0.32.0) and my breakpoints seem to no longer be getting hit. During debug, the breakpoint changes from a red circle to grey and if I hover over the breakpoint it displays "Access is denied". I've tried running as administrator with the same result. The Go module is a single file, as shown in the screenshot. The launch configuration is the default one created by VSCode, and is shown below. Any ideas?

[image]

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the "Access is denied" error. For VSCode not hitting breakpoints, can you try `"stopOnEntry": true` and inspect what source code paths the compiled binary's debug info contains, by entering `dlv sources` command from DEBUG CONSOLE while the debug session is active but stopped on entry. Often the issue occurs when the file paths the editor sees and the binary embeds in its debug info differ. (symlinks, bugs in handling windows paths, ...) I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

FYI for others searching, turns out that the debugger "dlv.exe" was being blocked by my antivirus software.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. 
It's confusing since from the DEBUG CONSOLE, I see the `dlv.exe` actually ran.